# How can my pipe client wait for the server

Tags: c, windows, pipe

I am implementing a named pipe IPC scheme in C running on windows, which is mostly working.
On the client side I create the pipe like this

```
void CreatePipex(const LPCWSTR pipename, InteruptHandler interruptHandler, unsigned char *USARTData)
{
  while (1)
   {
      pipes [_pipeIndex].handle = CreateFile(
         pipename,
         GENERIC_READ |
         GENERIC_WRITE,
         0,
         NULL,
         OPEN_EXISTING,
         0,
         NULL);

      // break if pipe was created
      if (pipes[_pipeIndex].handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
         wprintf(L"created pipe %s\n", pipename);
         break;
      }

        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {

        }
      // exit if pipe not created and not busy
      if (GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
      {
          wchar_t buf[256];
          FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
              NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
              buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
          wprintf(L"Could not create %s : %s %d\n",pipename, buf,GetLastError());
         //printf("could not create pipe %d\n", lastError);
         exit(-1);
      }
      if (!WaitNamedPipe(pipename, 20000))
      {
         wprintf(L"Could not open %s: 20 second wait timed out.\n",pipename);
         exit(-1);
      }

   }

   DWORD mode = PIPE_NOWAIT;
   if (!SetNamedPipeHandleState(pipes[_pipeIndex].handle, &mode, 0, 0))
   {
       wchar_t buf[256];
       FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
           NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
           buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
       wprintf(L"Could not set mode for %s : %s\n", pipename, buf);

      exit(-1);
   }
```

But if I run the client without the server the client pipe cannot be created

```
Could not create \\.\pipe\F0 : The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there a way of getting my client to wait for the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop (and sleep) until CreateFile returns something different from ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.